# Re-usable sidebar with custom content Semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a basic [`<Sidebar />`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar/) from semantic ui react. I want to be able to reuse this component across several pages -- passing different content in most cases.

Here is the re-usable Sidebar component

```
const SidebarExample = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState({ name: "visible" });

  return (
    <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
      <Sidebar
        as={Menu}
        animation="push"
        icon="labeled"
        inverted
        onHide={() => setVisible(false)}
        vertical
        visible={visible}
        width="thin"
      >
        <Menu.Item as="a">
          <Icon name="home" />
          Home
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as="a">
          <Icon name="gamepad" />
          Games
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as="a">
          <Icon name="camera" />
          Channels
        </Menu.Item>
      </Sidebar>

      <Sidebar.Pusher>
        <Segment>
          <Header as="h3">Application Content</Header>
          <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
          <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
          <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
          <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
        </Segment>
      </Sidebar.Pusher>
    </Sidebar.Pushable>
  );
};
```

My question is how can I pass custom content to `<Sidebar.Pusher>`?
Lets say I have a dashboard component where I import this sidebar. Shouldn't I be able to do something like this?

```
const blah = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> custom content </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const Dashboard = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1> Dashboard </h1>
        <SidebarExample content={blah} />;
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-merkle-023q1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since blah is functional component, you can pass it as a children

```
<SidebarExample><Blah/></SidebarExample>;

const Blah = props => { // make sure to name it as capital letter
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> custom content </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And inside SideBarExample call it as

```
<Sidebar.Pusher>
   {props.children}
 </Sidebar.Pusher>
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-wilson-khdlf?file=/src/components/Dashboard.js)

**Solution 2**:

You can also do the way you are doing, you can pass blah as a prop and render it by calling it as a function

```
<Sidebar.Pusher>
       {props.content()} // since blah is a function
  </Sidebar.Pusher>
```

Comment: Thanks for the multiple solutions, is there perf +/- with either solution or is it negligible? Basically, is one preferred over the other?

Comment: @DJ2 The first solution is more cleaner and should be preferred, where Blah is a functional component since it gives you flexibility to pass props to children easily

Answer (score 1):

You can use `children` props to pass children elements directly into their output

**Sidebar.js**

```
return (
    <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
      <Sidebar
        as={Menu}
        animation="push"
        icon="labeled"
        inverted
        onHide={() => setVisible(false)}
        vertical
        visible={visible}
        width="thin"
      >
        <Menu.Item as="a">
          <Icon name="home" />
          Home
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as="a">
          <Icon name="gamepad" />
          Games
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as="a">
          <Icon name="camera" />
          Channels
        </Menu.Item>
      </Sidebar>

      <Sidebar.Pusher>
        <Segment>
          <Header as="h3">Application Content</Header>
          <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
          <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
          <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
          <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
        {props.children} // show children
        </Segment>
      </Sidebar.Pusher>
    </Sidebar.Pushable>
  );
```

And pass your content in your components like this

```
const blah = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> custom content </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const Dashboard = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1> Dashboard </h1>
        <SidebarExample>
            {blah()} // add jsx here
        </SidebarExample>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Try this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-matsumoto-jis2r?file=/src/components/Sidebar.js)